# Move type assertion within function that returns any

Tags: go, switch-statement, any, type-assertion

I have the following example of generic Go function:

```
package main

func read(address uint16) any {

    switch address {
    case 1:
        return float64(0.5)
    case 2:
        return int(8)
    default:
        return "Hello"
    }

}

func main() {
    v1 := read(1)
    v2 := read(2)

    v1 = v1 / 2.5
    v2 = v2 * 4
}
```

which fails because of missing type assertion. See code on [go.dev/play](https://go.dev/play/p/WKf7TAaOyY_T).

In order to avoid this, I may use type assertion as per [Go tutorial on generics](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/generics):

```
v1 = v1.(float64) / 2.5
v2 = v2.(int) * 4
```

to correctly provide the type. However, I would like to create a generic method to read sensor values. Both the user and the compiler know that if `read(1)` is called then a float64 is returned, the same goes if `read(2)` is called which always returns an integer.

Bottom line: is there any way I can avoid the type-assertion syntax outside the function `read()`?

The only ugly way I can think of is to have different read functions like `readInt()` and `readFloat64()`, but I'd rather keep a generic method for reading.

Comment: That function doesn't have a type parameter and thus isn't "generic". Can you clearify what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to read different sensor values with a common function, aka `read()`. The return value may be `int` or `float64`, depending on the address I give in input.
If adding generic type T, as done [here](https://go.dev/play/p/EKNW1I5MZJs), still having some issues.

Comment: As per answer below, you may use generics as done [here](http://go.dev/play/p/XOmvYoxQqLm). This looks nicer, but I still need to specify the type when calling the function.

Comment: In your `read` function you decide the return type based on arbitrary run-time values, so obviously this function can't be statically type-checked. The answer you got below with generics works because you specify the types at the call site, thus giving enough type info to the compiler, *at compile time*. The only other way this *might* work at compile time is if return type inference worked with explicitly typed variables, e.g. `var v1 float64 = read(1)` but this feature isn't available at this time.

Answer (score 2):

> is there any way I can avoid the type-assertion syntax outside the function read()?

Yes, use generics to move the type assertion inside of the function.

```
func read[T any](address uint16) T {
    var result any
    switch address {
    case 1:
        result = float64(0.5)
    case 2:
        result = int(8)
    default:
        result = "Hello"
    }
    return result.(T)
}

func main() {
    v1 := read[float64](1)
    v2 := read[int](2)

    v1 = v1 / 2.5
    v2 = v2 * 4
    fmt.Println(v1, v2)
}
```